# Finger-four formation Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement the finger-four formation on Unity. Essentially, there will be a leader and 3 followers. The leader moves with left click on the plane and the others follow the leader. The formation will look like this:

```
                0
             1     2
                      3
```

The leader is 0 and the followers are 1, 2 and 3. When I left click, the leader should move to the clicked position and the others should follow. The followers need to be facing the same direction as they are facing right now and not face the leader. Could someone please help me out with this?
Thank you.

---

### EDIT 1:

I have already implemented the movement script. The leader is moving on left clicks on the plane. Here is the code I used for that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movementTry : MonoBehaviour {
private Transform myTransform;              // this transform
private Vector3 destinationPosition;        // The destination Point
private float destinationDistance;          // The distance between myTransform and destinationPosition

public float moveSpeed;                     // The Speed the character will move



void Start () {
    myTransform = transform;                            // sets myTransform to this GameObject.transform
    destinationPosition = myTransform.position;         // prevents myTransform reset
}

void Update () {

    // keep track of the distance between this gameObject and destinationPosition
    destinationDistance = Vector3.Distance(destinationPosition, myTransform.position);

    if(destinationDistance < .5f){      // To prevent shakin behavior when near destination
        moveSpeed = 0;
    }
    else if(destinationDistance > .5f){         // To Reset Speed to default
        moveSpeed = 5;
    }


    // Moves the Player if the Left Mouse Button was clicked
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&& GUIUtility.hotControl ==0) {

        Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, myTransform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float hitdist = 0.0f;

        if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist)) {
            Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
            destinationPosition = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
            myTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
    }

    // Moves the player if the mouse button is hold down
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)&& GUIUtility.hotControl ==0) {

        Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, myTransform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float hitdist = 0.0f;

        if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist)) {
            Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
            destinationPosition = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
            myTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
        //  myTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(myTransform.position, destinationPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // To prevent code from running if not needed
    if(destinationDistance > .5f){
        myTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(myTransform.position, destinationPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you post your code and the results you get when you run it, that  will help.  You can edit your question to add more information.

Comment: I am completely lost in this. I tried a lot of things. I am able to move the character but I have no clues on how to make the rest follow him. I will update the original post with my movement script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution. It is actually incredibly simple. If anyone needs to know, this is how it is done.

Create an empty gameobject. lets call it "GameUnits"
Drag all of the other objects that you wish to move in this formation into the GameUnits.
add a new C# script to GameUnits and copy and paste the code mentioned above. 
Left clicking on a plane now will move the entire group in its exact formation.